# Recursive lazy loading in async SQLAlchemy: Greenlet spawn error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

I'm trying to load and serialize a deeply nested model using SQLAlchemy into a json response (using pydantic `ParentType`), which seems difficult using an async engine.

I have a `Parent` db model, which is related to a `Child`, which in turn is related to `GrandChild` and so on...

Now, I can eagerly load the 1st level of relationships using:

```
stmt = select(Parent).filter(Parent.id == id)
stmt = stmt.options(joinedload(getattr(Parent, "children")))
```

But this will fail because `Child`'s `children` will need to be lazy-loaded.

I can eager load every relation of my Parent model recursively and so on... but this method will go past my required depth of `ParentType` and will result in extra queries that I do not need.

How can I lazy-load in async according to my serialization model?

Options:

- To pair the serialization model and eager load the required relations?
- Somehow create a new greenlet to fetch the relation?